# Textview inside scrollview begin of text

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview inside a scrollview.
I scroll to the bottom of the text and I need to know when the scrollview arrieve to the begin of the text. When the scrollview can't move up.

I hope you understand the question, if you need any clarification, tell me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help, but I think this is the closer approach you could find for a ScrollView:

[ScrollView#onOverScrolled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I don't know how to use it, the event is protected and I can't override it, if you can tell me how to use, please. I found the function canScrollVertically(int direction) but it was added in api 14 and my minimum api is 9.